# Count set of number has the same difference in integer array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array : [1,1,1,1,2,3,4], count all set of same difference in array
※difference value for each set in an array can be not the same

```
Way to count one set have same difference:
-1,0,1  -> count = 1 with diff = 1
1,1,1   -> count = 1 with diff = 0
1,2,3,4 -> count = 3 with diff = 1 ([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4])
0,1     -> not count
0,1,3   -> not count
0,1,1,2 -> not count , althought it has 0,1 and 1,2 with diff = 1 but it is not continous

As the above array  [1,1,1,1,2,3,4] count = 6
There are 6 sets has the same difference value:
 [1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1] with difference = 0
 [1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4] with difference = 1
```

Here is my brute force approach O(n2)
Can I use DP with memorization to improve it more efficiently?

```js
 function run(pArray){
      var count = 0;
      var length = pArray.length;
      for(var i = 0;i<length - 2;i++){          
        var nextIdx = i + 1;
        var diff = pArray[nextIdx]-pArray[i];          
        while(true){
          nextIdx ++;
        
          if(nextIdx > length - 1){
            break;
          }    
          if(pArray[nextIdx] - pArray[nextIdx - 1] !== diff){
            break;
          }else{
            count ++;
          }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(count);
    }
    
    run([1,1,1,1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: Please make your question clear. What are the inputs to algorithm the array and a difference value ? In your example are the inputs arr = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4] and difference = 1 ?

Comment: Hi SomeDue
I have edited question more clearly.
the input is just an integer array (at lat line I call function run(<array>)
the output is a count sets

Comment: sorry your question still is unclear. What does "※difference value can be not the same" mean?

Comment: I have explained more with the example :
" 
    As the above array  [1,1,1,1,2,3,4] count = 6
    There are 6 sets has the same difference value:
        [1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1] with difference = 0
        and [1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4] with difference = 1
"

Comment: Ok so all sets that has same difference among its elements i.e. diff( element - element_to_its_left) is the same for all elements - need to be counted. Now one more question : why won't you count [1,1] as one more set for the difference 0?

Comment: Probably a set in the answer should have at least 3 elements such that there are at least two pairs that has the same difference.

Comment: Yes, the set has at least two pairs and must continuous has the same difference. 
[0,1,1,2] isn't count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your latest comment, it seems you do care about the order of elements in the array. Hence it need not be sorted and in that case the number of sets could evaluate to zero as in the case [1,2,1,2,1].

In that case it could be done in `O(n)`.

The idea is:

If you find a matching difference increment a count variable, update
   the result as result = result + count.

Take an example [1,1,1,1]. You don't need to consider indices 0,1.

Take index 2 see if arr[2] - arr[1] == arr[1] - arr[0] then increment
   count from 0 to 1 , add it to result.

Take index 3 see if arr[3] - arr[2] == arr[2] - arr[1] , yes it is
   equal, then increment count to 2 , add it to result. Now result = 1 +
   2 = 3.

You get the idea, as long as you get elements that satisfy the
   criteria arr[i] - arr[i-1] == arr[i-1] - arr[i-2] you keep adding the
   next higher value. So result = 1 + 2 + 3 +....i-2 and so on for a
   given index i

If you don't find matching difference, reset count variable to zero
   and start afresh.

Note: I am not that familiar with Javascript, but it looks like:

```html
<div>
    <script>
      function countSets(arr) {
        if (arr === undefined || arr.length < 3) return 0;
        let count = 0;
        let res = 0;
        for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; ++i) {
          if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] === arr[i - 1] - arr[i - 2]) {
            count++;
          } else {
            count = 0;
          }
          res += count;
        }
        return res;
      }
      console.log("[1, 1, 1] -> " + countSets([1, 1, 1]))
      console.log("[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] -> " + countSets([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]))
      console.log("[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4] -> " + countSets([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
      console.log("[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5] -> " + countSets([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]))
      console.log("[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> " + countSets([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
      console.log("[1, 2, 1, 2, 1] -> " + countSets([1, 2, 1, 2, 1]))
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It great!
but you can't sort an array, for example [1,2,1,2,1] will count = 1,but correct answer is 0 because difference are 1,-1,1,-1 so it didn't count.

Comment: So the formula for the continous set has the same difference will be: f(n) = (n-2) + (n-3) +...+(n-n) ? . ex [1,2,3,4,5] => f(5) = (5-2)  + (5-3 ) + (5-4) + (5-5) = 6

Comment: At JS is the same 1 != -1 . I mean the array shouldn't sort, [1,2,1,2,1] -> [1,1,1,2,2] then count will be 1. Anyway Thank you SomeDude, how can you know that? at first, I think some think like fibonacci formula but it not work :(

Comment: Yeah, I just realized. funny. I deleted my earlier comment. All you have to do is remove arr.sort(), I added your testcase too.